# OxyPlot Change Interval On Zoom Level

Tags: c#, oxyplot

I'm trying to make my plot change it's interval type depending on the level of zoom but I'm not sure how to achieve this. I'm using a `DateTimeAxis` and would like it to start at Days. Then zooming out would change from days to months, finally to years. Zooming in would change from Days to hours, maybe seconds if this type of behavior is even possible.

Currently I have my axes setup as follows:

```
public DateTimeAxis HorizontalAxis
    {
        get
        {
            return new DateTimeAxis
            {
                Position = AxisPosition.Bottom,
                Minimum = DateTimeAxis.ToDouble(Start),
                Maximum = DateTimeAxis.ToDouble(End),
                MajorStep = double.NaN,
                MinimumMajorStep = 0,
                MinorStep = double.NaN,
                MinimumMinorStep = 0,
                AbsoluteMinimum = DateTimeAxis.ToDouble(Start),
                AbsoluteMaximum = DateTimeAxis.ToDouble(End),
                MinorIntervalType = DateTimeIntervalType.Hours,
                IntervalType = DateTimeIntervalType.Days,
                Title = " Date Time Axis Title "
            };
        }
    }

public LinearAxis VerticalAxis
    {
        get
        {
            return new LinearAxis
            {
                Position = AxisPosition.Left,
                Minimum = SetPoint - 4,
                Maximum = SetPoint + 4,
                MajorStep = double.NaN,
                MinimumMajorStep = 0,
                MinorStep = 0.5,
                MinimumMinorStep = 0,
                AbsoluteMinimum = SetPoint - 4,
                AbsoluteMaximum = SetPoint + 4,
                MinorTickSize = 0,
                Title = " Linear Axis Title "
            };
        }
    }
```

If this type of behavior is not possible I would also ask if there is a way to get hours to show when zooming in from days. When making a default plot this was the behavior I saw.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I know I just posted this question but perhaps there are other people who are interested in getting this type of behavior.

To dynamically change the axis I used the AxisChanged event described [Here](http://www.nudoq.org/#!/Packages/OxyPlot.WindowsForms/OxyPlot/Axis/E/AxisChanged)

From there I created an output message to see what properties were changing in the axes. I found that the `Scale`, `Minor Step Size`, and `Major Step Size` are what changes on zooming. Implementing a simple if statement to check the scale I was able to get the behavior I desired.

```
    private async void Horizontal_AxisChanged(object sender, AxisChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        DateTimeAxis horizontal = sender as DateTimeAxis;

        if(horizontal.Scale > 100)
        {
            horizontal.IntervalType = DateTimeIntervalType.Hours;
        }

        else if(horizontal.Scale < 100)
        {
            horizontal.IntervalType = DateTimeIntervalType.Days;
        }
    }
```